# How to test JBoss server is started from external java application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

how can i test from external java application that my server jboss is running ?

I've a JBoss (4.2.3) server and I want know from a stand-alone java application if that server i started or not.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I don't have access to the jboss machine and the jmx console is disabled for safety reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check inspecting the running processes if you have access to the machine where jboss is running.

If you don't have access to the machine, then you'll have to try to connect to it, checking if it's listening to the http port or if you can reach it via JMX, but then you can't be sure if it's really not running or if some firewall rule is blocking your request.

Comment: I don't have access to the jboss machine and the jmx console is disabled for safety reasons.

Comment: then the best you can do is to check the http port, but you can't be 100% sure

Comment: one thing you can try is to add a shutdown/startup hook that send you some notification like http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-configuration/intercepting-jboss-shutdown. Again, it's not 100% reliable

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution if you are running on linux is to execute a shell command like

```
 ps -ef | grep jboss >> somelog.txt
```

execute it using Runtime class using exec() method in Runtime and check the output of that command from your java program

Surely there might be some other better alternative , but this is just a simple thought

Comment: I don't have access to the jboss machine.

Comment: Ok. Do you know ip address and port number of the machine you are running jobss?

Comment: If yes , then try to access the url from your java program (you can google for that) and get the response and process according to that

Comment: This solution is the first that I found "googling" a bit, but I was looking for something better.